# using ajax to create new table row and form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i am trying to make this ajax to submit my form but it only goes to the very last errror(Unexpected error! Try again).when i remove the datatype:json part,it then alerts undefined

```
    function ajax(action,id){
    if(action =="save")
        data = $("#userinfo").serialize()+"&action="+action;
    else if(action == "delete"){
        data = "action="+action+"&item_id="+id;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "ajax.php", 
        data : data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){
            if(response.success == "1"){
                if(action == "save"){
                    $(".dert-form").fadeOut("fast",function(){
                    alert(here first);
                    }); 
                }else if(action == "delete"){
                    alert(here  to delete);
                }
            }
        },
        error: function(res){
            alert("Unexpected error! Try again.");
        }
    });
}
```

here is ajax.php

```
if($action == "save"){
/* Check for blanks */ 
$err = "You have blank fields. ";
echo json_encode(
    array(
        "success" => "0",
        "msg"  => $err,                 
    )    
);

}
```

Comment: your first problem is that your current code has syntax errors. `alert(here first);` and `alert(here  to delete);` contain invalid syntax. You need to put quotes around those strings.

Comment: @Sid thanks point taken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example of your code with some adjustments:

```
function ajax(action,id){
    action = 'save';
    if(action =="save")
        data = $("#userinfo").serialize()+"&action="+action;
    else if(action == "delete"){
        data = "action="+action+"&item_id="+id;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET", 
        url: "http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/package_list", 
        data: data,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            if(response.success == "1"){
                if(action == "save"){
                    $(".dert-form").fadeOut("fast",function(){
                      alert("here first");
                    }); 
                }
                else if(action == "delete"){
                    alert("here  to delete");
                }
            }
        },
        error: function(res, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log("Unexpected error! Try again.");
        }
    });
}
```

I'm hitting a data.gov API endpoint and logging the response to the console. Note, the `dataType` has to be `jsonp` since I'm make a cross-domain request. You can also look at the [JSBin I created with the above code](http://jsbin.com/vonumepe/1/edit?js,console,output).

Comment: thanks for this +2,but how do i get to see the error from the php script.as you can see from my edit php above.

Comment: @user3253289 errors show up in the console. Just Google "open console for <your browser here>" and you should be able to find instructions on how to open the console for your browser.

Comment: the link you put in your comment is inactive for thr google open console

Comment: @user3253289 that wasn't meant to be a link. Replace '<your browser here>' with the name of your browser and search for that on Google.

Comment: I do not see any javascript related errors i see only things related to css

Comment: do i have to set the error reporting in php.ini in this case.

Answer (score 0):

use json format for data instead or query string

```
 data = {"action":action,"item_id":id};
```

Comment: why should i not use a query string yet i might have different actions to take,ie i may need to pass an action like save to db Also some actions may not require an id just like save.Cold you clarify .And where do i fix that code in the picture

Comment: @user3253289 `data` can be anything you want pretty much (object, string or array). From the [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings): "Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests." So, it all depends on your implementation and how you want use it.

Comment: @Muhammad Ali +1 for showing me a new way to do this